# Find minimum distance in matrix

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, matrix

**[Challenge URL](http://acm.scu.edu.cn/soj/problem.action?id=3330):**
http://acm.scu.edu.cn/soj/problem.action?id=3330

> Windy has a matrix A with size N*M which only contains 0 or 1. The
> distance between Axy and Apq is:  |x-p| + |y-q| Can you help Windy to
> find the minimum distance between Aij and 1? Output the sum of the
> minimum distance of all Aij.
>
> Input
>
> The first line of input is the number of test case. For each
> test case: The first line contains two integers N and M. The next N
> lines each contains M integers, Aij. There is a blank line before each
> test case.
> 1 <= N,M <= 1000
> 0 <= Aij <= 1
> There is at least one Aij=1.
>
> Output
>
> For each test case output the answer on a single line.

Sample Input and output can be seen at the URL.

But this one when I use BFS, it is too slow, and I guess there can be a better implementation.

## Update for a new code

I find DP can help in this problem, I passed the test case in the question, but get runtime error for the further test, please help me fix this code, thank you!

```
//import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;
//import java.util.LinkedList;


//3300 BFS
public class WindyMatrix {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = scanner.nextInt();
        int row, col, i, j, result,cnt,now;
        int[][] M = new int[1000][1000];
        int[][] DP = new int[1000][1000];
        // 0 -> 1; -1 -> 0 not get dis
        while (t != 0) {
            cnt = now = result = 0;

            row = scanner.nextInt();
            col = scanner.nextInt();
            for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                    M[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
                    if(M[i][j]==0){
                        DP[i][j] = -1;
                        cnt++;//cnt for 0 position
                    }
                    else {
                        DP[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            while (cnt!=0) {
                // 找now进行+1
                for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                        if(DP[i][j]==now){
                            if(i-1>=0 && DP[i-1][j]==-1){
                                DP[i-1][j] = now+1;
                                result+=now+1;
                                cnt--;
                            }
                            if(i+1<row && DP[i+1][j]==-1){
                                DP[i+1][j] = now+1;
                                result+=now+1;
                                cnt--;
                            }
                            if(j-1>=0 && DP[i][j-1]==-1){
                                DP[i][j-1] = now+1;
                                result+=now+1;
                                cnt--;
                            }
                            if(j+1<col&&DP[i][j+1]==-1){
                                DP[i][j-1] = now+1;
                                result+=now+1;
                                cnt--;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                now++;
            }
            
            System.out.println(result);
            t--;
        }
    }
}
```

older one, time exceed.

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.LinkedList;

// 3300 BFS
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = scanner.nextInt();
        int row, col, i, j, result, distance, cnt, nextcnt,t1,t2;
        int[][] M = new int[1000][1000];
        Queue list = new LinkedList();
        boolean find_flag;
        while (t != 0) {
            result = 0;
            row = scanner.nextInt();
            col = scanner.nextInt();
            for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                    M[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
                }
            }
            // compute the distance for every 0
            for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                    if (M[i][j] == 0) {
                        // BFS
                        distance = 0;
                        cnt = 0;
                        if (j - 1 >= 0) {
                            list.add(i);
                            list.add(j - 1);
                            cnt++;
                        }
                        if (j + 1 < col) {
                            cnt++;
                            list.add(i);
                            list.add(j + 1);
                        }
                        if (i - 1 >= 0) {
                            cnt++;
                            list.add(i-1);
                            list.add(j);
                        }
                        if (i + 1 < row) {
                            cnt++;
                            list.add(i+1);
                            list.add(j);
                        }
                        nextcnt = 0;
                        find_flag = false;
                        while (true) {
                            distance++;
                            for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
                                t1 = (int) list.poll();
                                t2 = (int) list.poll();
                                if (M[t1][t2] == 1) {
                                    find_flag = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                                if (t2 - 1 >= 0) {
                                    list.add(t1);
                                    list.add(t2-1);
                                    nextcnt++;
                                }
                                if (t2 + 1 < col) {
                                    list.add(t1);
                                    list.add(t2+1);
                                    nextcnt++;
                                }
                                if (t1 - 1 >= 0) {
                                    nextcnt++;
                                    list.add(t1-1);
                                    list.add(t2);
                                }
                                if (t1 + 1 < row) {
                                    nextcnt++;
                                    list.add(t1+1);
                                    list.add(t2);
                                }
                            }
                            if (find_flag) {
                                break;
                            }
                            cnt = nextcnt;
                            nextcnt = 0;
                        }
                        list.clear();
                        result += distance;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(result);
            t--;
        }
    }
}
```

So if I want to make it finish in the time frame, what can be improved?

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview I hope you get some good answers.

Comment: `Sample Input and output can be seen at the URL.` I can see no URL

Comment: sorry, it is url on challenge, it is not obvious, I fix it.